# Organize Firefox bookmarks

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

I have over 100 bookmark URLs in a firefox bookmark folder.

Is there any tool to organize them more easily than with the build-in Bookmark Organizer? I'm looking for a drag&drop editor.

Comment: create a new folder in the bookmark oganizer and use drag 'n' drop to move the URLs, press CTRL to select multiple URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has drag and drop as molly suggests, you will get used to it in 5 min. once you figure out how to DnD.
Dont forget to **export HTML** and **backup** your bookmarks!

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what Molly suggested in the comments, if you want some juice in your bookmarks handling this looks pretty nice - [Incredible Bookmarks](http://www.visibotech.com/IncredibleBookmarks/)